# React: Dependent controlled select elements should change their value when state doesn't match an option

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following situation:

Two controlled select elements. Selecting an option in the first select element changes the options of the second select element. This works fine.

But: When the list of options of the second select element doesn't contain the current state value of this element, its view changes to the "unselected" option (empty value). But there is no change event which would trigger setting the state accordingly.

So: The state keeps the old value, but this no longer matches a selectable option in the list.

Is it possible to detect if the state of the select input element is not available in the control's option list?

EDIT: Code for the select components

```js
const Select = ({identifier, className, to, dal, setTemplateOptions, model, value, message, valueChanged, touched, evalInScope, fieldTouched, fieldRef, hideExpression}) => {

    const [labelProp, setLabelProp] = useState(to.labelProp?to.labelProp:"label");
    const [valueProp] = useState(to.valueProp?to.valueProp:"value");

    const setNewValue = e => {
        console.log(`SELECT.${identifier} changed its value`);
        if(to.multiple) {
            let resultValues = [];
            for(let opt of fieldRef.current.selectedOptions) {
                resultValues.push(opt.value);
            }
            valueChanged(resultValues, true);
        } else {
            valueChanged(e.target.value, false);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            if(dal) {
                // console.log("DAL UPDATE on field " + identifier);
                let jsonResponse = await DAL.request(dal);
                // console.log("Result from DAL request");
                // console.dir(jsonResponse);
                setTemplateOptions(prevTemplateOptions => {
                    return {...prevTemplateOptions, options: jsonResponse}
                })

                // Check to see if values are available in the options, otherwise remove this/these value(s)
                if(typeof value === "string" && value !== "") {
                    let found = false;
                    for(let option of jsonResponse) {
                        if(option[valueProp] === value) {
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!found) {
                        //valueChanged("", false);
                        // console.log("Value " + value + " wurde in den Options des Feldes " + identifier + " nicht gefunden!");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        fetchData();
    }, [dal]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(to.labelExpression) {
            // example $item.cn + ': ' + $item.value
            to.options.forEach($item => {
                let result = eval(to.labelExpression);
                $item.exprLabel = result;
             });
             setLabelProp("exprLabel");
        }
    }, [to.options])

    return (
        <>
         {!hideExpression || !evalInScope(hideExpression, {model}) ? <div className={className + " mb-4"}>
                <label><b>{to.label ? to.label : identifier} {!to.disabled && to.required?<span style={{color: "red"}}>*</span>: ""}</b></label>
                <select value={value}
                    className="form-control"
                    disabled={to.disabled}
                    onChange={setNewValue}
                    onBlur={fieldTouched}
                    ref={fieldRef} multiple={to.multiple}>
                        {to.multiple?null:<option value="">{to.noChoiceLabel}</option>}
                        {to.options.map((option, i) => (
                            <option key={i} value={option[valueProp]}>{option[labelProp]}</option>
                        ))}
                </select>
                {touched ? <span style={{color: "red"}}>{message}</span> : null}
            </div> : null }
        </>
    )
}
```

to.options contains the options of the select. This can change when running setTemplateOptions "one level up" on the "Element" component which keeps common code in one place. But when the options change to a list not containing the current "value", the select element will show the empty option, but the value state is not updated due to a missing change event.

EDIT2: I've created a stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v8glq9) which breaks down the problem. Notice, that the model of the select element points to "building3", which is not available in the select options. But the model still shows building3, even though the select doesn't have this option

Comment: Please provide some code snippets as examples to demonstrate the above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy default html way of having an event fire if the current value of a select is not an option.

You can probably do some things with form validation and checking if the element is valid, but that's not the approach I'm going with here.

There's two approaches you can go through here:

You can clear out invalid values when they exist, so you only ever have valid values in your select elements.

You can check for invalid values as part of your validation cycles. Then while the select still has an invalid value, it's considered that way and you can ignore it.

I'll focus on clearing out invalid values for the moment:

```
// First, map through the value option and remove anything that doesn't exist within the options array.
  /**
   * values that remain after you remove all values that are invalid in the current options
   */
  const validValue = useMemo(() => {
    if (!value || (Array.isArray(value) && !value.length)) {
      // Nothing to do here
      return value;
    }
    const valueArr = Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value];
    const optionValues = Object.fromEntries(
      to.options.map(option => [option[valueProp], true])
    );

    const newValues = valueArr.filter(value => optionValues[value]);
    return Array.isArray(value) ? newValues : newValues[0] ?? '';
  }, [to.options, value, valueProp]);

  // update the state when there's things to fix.
  useEffect(() => {
    /*
     * call valueChanged whenever valid value differs from value.
     */
    if (
      Array.isArray(value)
        ? value.length !== validValue.length
        : value !== validValue
    ) {
      valueChanged(validValue, Array.isArray(value), true);
    }
  }, [value, validValue]);
```

That's the end of the story for this, though there were also a few updates in `Element.js` as well to help make sure the validity is being set properly with this effect.

```
  const isMounting = useRef(true);
  // Only re-run setFieldState here when it's not the first mount.
  // The value is already correct since it's being set correctly as initial State
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounting.current) {
      return;
    }
    if (templateOptions.disabled) setFieldState({ valid: true, message: '' });
    else setFieldState(validateField());
  }, [templateOptions.disabled]);
```

At the end of the Element component before the return:

```
  // Toggle isMounting to false
  useEffect(() => {
    isMounting.current = false;
  },[]);
```

Here's the running code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vmfsg6?file=src%2FinputElements%2FSelect.js

For the other way of just making sure that the values are counted as invalid, then a change to the `validateField` function is all that's needed:

```
  // moved this up so it is defined when validateField is called
  const [templateOptions, setTemplateOptions] = useState(
    field.templateOptions || {}
  );

  const validateField = () => {
    let value = model[field.key];
    let isArray = Array.isArray(value);
    if (templateOptions?.options) {
      if (isArray ? value?.length : value) {
        // value to check should be based on the existing options
        const valueArr = Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value];
        const optionValues = Object.fromEntries(
          templateOptions.options.map(option => [
            option[templateOptions.valueProp || 'value'],
            true
          ])
        );

        const newValues = valueArr.filter(value => optionValues[value]);
        value = Array.isArray(value) ? newValues : newValues[0] ?? '';
      }
    }

    return !(
      field.templateOptions &&
      !field.templateOptions.disabled &&
      field.templateOptions.required &&
      (isArray ? !value.length : !value)
    )
      ? { valid: true, message: '' }
      : { valid: false, message: 'This field is required' };
  };
```

It may also be a good idea to run the re-validate effect whenever the template options change.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (templateOptions.disabled) set$FieldState({ valid: true, message: '' });
    else set$FieldState(validateField());
  }, [templateOptions.disabled, templateOptions.options]);
```

Running code for this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ohhram?file=src%2FElement.js

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive feedback. I will definitely check this out, when I'm back from the hospital. If I won't be able to test this before, you will still get the full bounty

Comment: The solutions are both perfect. Thank you so much. I only need to find out which one I will end up using

Comment: I like the second solution very much, because it keeps the value for later (possibly asynchronous) updates, but if the initialmodel has a valid value like building1 at the start, it will still render the form as invalid... can we do something about it?

Comment: @devnull69 I fixed the logic, I was accidentally using the wrong field to build up the list of valid options. I was using `field.key` instead of `templateOptions.valueProp`. Hope this works for you!